# X is binomially distributed, and Y is binomially distributed. What distribution does X+Y follow?

Tags: self-study, binomial-distribution, poisson-binomial-distribution

We know that

$X$ follows $\mathrm{Bin}(n_1,p_1)$, $Y$ follows $\mathrm{Bin}(n_2,p_2)$, $X$ and $Y$ are independent. What does $X+Y$ follow?

I know the answer, that if $p_1=p_2=p$ then $X+Y$ follow $\mathrm{Bin}(n_1+n_2,p)$ but I do not quite get it. I tried to match $X+Y$ to the criterion of Bin distribution:

- Success/fail
- Independence, yes since Y and X are independent, and all $X$'s are independent with themselves, and all Y's are independent with themselves.
- same p. yes, If we are allowed to assume that.

Also, what more can we say about $X+Y$?

Comment: Do you mean: you're throwing a die and flipping a coin. You then look at the sum of 'one's + 'head's?

Comment: The situation at hand is not given, although yes your situation seem to be accurate since X: # of 1 follows Bin and Y: # of heads follow Bin

Comment: [This thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29998/sum-of-independent-binomial-random-variables-with-different-probabilities) is related to this question.

Comment: A very closely related thread at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5347 addresses this question for the case of more than two binomial variables (with a focus on a much larger number of them). Of course all the exact solutions offered there apply to this simpler case!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the [Poisson-binomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution) distribution.

A number of answers here discuss this distribution.

We can say a number of things about it. Here are a few examples:

- we can compute its mean and variance using basic properties of mean and of variance under independence.
- [It is unimodal*](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15687/the-unimodality-of-a-generalised-binomial-distribution/15688#15688)

* with the proviso that if two adjacent outcomes are equally maximally probable, we still call that 'unimodal'.

- if both $p_i$ values are very small, $X+Y$ may be well approximated by a Poisson distribution
- [Le Cam's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Cam%27s_theorem) applies to it

we might say many more things.

Comment: Can you provide a proof for this more simple case?

Comment: A proof of what?

Comment: Proce that if $X$ follows $\mathrm{Bin}(n_1,p_1)$, $Y$ follows $\mathrm{Bin}(n_2,p_2)$, $X$ and $Y$ are independent, and $p_1=p_2=p$ then $X+Y$ follow $\mathrm{Bin}(n_1+n_2,p)$.

Comment: That would definitely fall under the 'routine question' part of the `self-study` [tag wiki info](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) (*q.v.*), to which helpful hints would be given if you show us where you had difficulty. The deleted answer by @Zen was the start of one way to approach that question. (I presume it got deleted because you asked about the Poisson binomial, a more complicated question to which his answer wasn't as directly useful.) -- what have you tried?